# Selenium Webelement in two methods fail when called

Tags: java, selenium

I have a key class that contains reusable methods. I'm trying to use WebElement in two methods. They care called close together. I know that it's the webelement thats failing because I can code it without having it in two methods and it works fine. How can I properly do this without it failing when the method containing the webelement is called? (No such element exception)

public class key {

```
WebElement webElement = null;

public void hoover(String path) throws InterruptedException{

    webElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath(path));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(webElement).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000); 
}


public void click(String path) throws InterruptedException{

    webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path));
    webElement.click();//This opens menu list
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Another class uses like this:

```
    session.navigate("url");
session.hoover("someTab");
Assert.assertTrue(session.isElementPresent("otherSub"), "Element not present");
session.click("otherSub");

    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
a openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:363)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
at com.salesforce.util.Keywords.actionHoover(Keywords.java:101)
at com.salesforce.testcases.SmokeTest.topMenuTest(SmokeTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Please wait for element after navigate to url. sometime element not immediately available.

Comment: Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    WebElement we = null;
    we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(urEleId)));
    if (we != null) {
        // Do Something if found
    } else {
        // Do Something if not found    
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you do not wait for the element to be visible. This can be caused by the fact that you ask for it before it is available(before it is loaded into the page). Selenium acts as an user, so you need to tell it to wait for the element to be visible and then get it, not just instantly get it

```
public void clickElementWhenReady(By locator, int timeout) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
    element.click();
}
```

You could implement something like that in order to pool for the element for a period of time and throw the error afterwards

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried that but that's not the problem. It won't even hoover over the tab.

Comment: I figured it out, I didnt load the properties ... OR.getPropery(xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Was missing OR.getProperty()

```
webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(path)));
webElement.click();//This opens menu list
Thread.sleep(5000);
```